# extend background color to entire html email

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<body bgcolor="red">
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<!--table code --> 
 </table>
 </body>
```

However there is still a white border left along the margin of the email. How do i remove that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<body bgcolor="red" style="margin:0">
```

or in old HTML

```
<body bgcolor="red" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
```

Comment: It is still showing a white margin in outlook and other emails

Comment: maybe because outlooks view panel has a white border? this is an application background you can't modify. make a large document and have a look at where the scroll bars are displayed. this is the real border of yout HTML email.

Comment: can't say much more. maybe the HTML is invalid? to few information to have any further suggestions.